# Is my UK ISP blocking a legitimate website?

Tags: internet, webserver, isp, web, blocking

UK ISPs are not well known by me for blocking websites for censorship other than blocking illegal sites such as child porn or torrent sites, yet when trying to access PubMed ([Desktop Site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) or [Mobile Site](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)) on any device through my WiFi router, I get a “server not found” message.

[image: screenshot from mobile for mobile site]
screenshot from mobile for mobile site

[image: screenshot from mobile for desktop site]
screenshot from mobile for desktop site

I am in the UK and PubMed is a US site, so I thought maybe they  have now started to block anyone outside the US. However, if I activate NordVPN and connect to a UK server, or use my mobile phone service connection, I can access the websites, so I know it is not geographical blocking by PubMed.

I tried Firefox and Google Chrome yet I get the same result. When trying on a laptop off NordVPN, I also get an ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED included in Chrome’s error page if that helps.

All browsers on all devices are set to clear their caches upon closing, and after the comment from @LPChip about DNS flushing, I made sure there was no [persistent DNS cache](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/31/clear-dns-cache-ios/) in my iPad to test the theory, and the problem is still there.

I also tried power-cycling the router as suggested by @Tetsujin but there is no change. The problem still exists.

There are no firewalls on my devices blocking these web addresses. Could my ISP be blocking my access or could there be something on my devices? Being that it affects all laptops, tablets and mobile phones, I am leaning towards the idea it is not the devices.

Comment: It can be a simple matter of them changing IP addresses, and you have an old version in your cache. Have you flushed your DNS then cleared your cache? What happens if you open the page in another browser that you never visited the site in before?

Comment: @LPChip - All browsers are set to flush the cache when closing to ensure no problems like that occur. Can your theory be correct when I am able to access via NordVPN then whilst keeping the browser open, if NordVPN is disconnected, I am no longer able to access the site?

Comment: NordVPN will set your browser's DNS to its services, so yes, if you close NordVPN, it will not reach the NordVPN DNS services and thus not find the site. This is by design to prevent data leakage in case someone hijacks your connection in an attempt to intercept date from your connection.

Comment: No issue here via a Virgin connection. What's your ISP? Have you tried using a different DNS in your router, or power-cycling it so it forgets its existing tables?

Comment: @Tetsujin - ISP is BT. I will try power-cycling the router and update

Comment: @Tetsujin - I tried power-cycling the router and the problem is still there. No change

Comment: I'd try swapping to wired, just in case, &/or changing the DNS server, just try 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 for now. After that, I'd ring BT… you *know* how much fun that will be ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I get a "server not found" message.

This seems to be a DNS resolution issue with those particular links, which appears to be unrelated to just a single ISP.

Using the links provided in your original question, switching networks between a wired cable provider and a mobile (4G) network both based in the US consistently yielded a failure to connect and successful connection, respectively. However, using just https://www.nih.gov/ worked on both.

Unfortunately, this likely means there isn't much that can be done to resolve this matter on your end, other than being patient or using another network to access the site e.g. NordVPN.

---

*As noted in the comments, switching your DNS resolvers might help as an alternative to using another network*.